# Android animation for selected Canvas

Tags: java, android, animation, android-canvas, android-animation

I've created a circle, drawn a string around the circle and a line (arrow) in my `onDraw()` method.

```
public class Circle extends Activity {  

  public class OuterCircle extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    private Animation anim;
    Path path = new Path();
    private static final String s = "Hello world example";

    public OuterCircle(Context context) {
      super(context);
      init();
    }

    private void init() {
      paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
      paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
      paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
      paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    }

    private void drawStringOnCircle(Canvas c) {
      path.addCircle(getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2, 180, Direction.CW);
      c.drawTextOnPath(s, path, 0, 10, paint);
      setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    private void createAnimation() {
      anim = new RotateAnimation(0, 360, getWidth()/2, getHeight()/2);
      anim.setRepeatMode(Animation.RESTART);
      anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      anim.setDuration(100L);
      startAnimation(anim);
    }

    public void onDraw(Canvas c) {      
      int cx = getWidth()/2;
      int cy = getHeight()/2;

      if (anim == null) {
             createAnimation();
      }

      c.drawCircle(cx, cy, 170, paint);      
      drawStringOnCircle(c);
      c.drawLine(cx, cy, cx, cy+170, paint); // do not include this line in animation
    }
  }

  OuterCircle = compassView;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    compassView = new DrawCompass(this);
    setContentView(compassView);
  }
}
```

I want to apply the animation only to the circle and the text around it (rotate the circle and the text around it using Android animation). The line I've drawn inside the circle must be stationary ( animation should not apply to the line). However, the above code is applying the animation to all the 3 `Canvas`. What changes should I make?

Also, I want to add a `TextView` in the middle of the circle. Can anyone share me some idea?

Comment: When is onDraw(Canvas c) called? Only one time or in a loop? If it's in a loop you can rotate everything but the line with the canvas.
If not you need the line on it's own element/View

Comment: I'm not calling the `onDraw()` separately. I've modified my code so that you could have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a new `View` which only draws the line and doesn't animate that.
Then in your layout you can draw the Line-View ontop of the OuterCirle-View or you do it in code with `addView(lineView)`.

The same way you can add a `TextView`

UPDATE: With `setContentView()` you should set a `View` which can contain other Views -> A Layout like `RelativeLayout`. And in this Layout you can add more than one `View` by calling `RelativeLayout.addView(childView)`. This way you can add the rotating Circle, then the line and then a `TextView` if you want.

Comment: Hi @Day, thanks for your quick answer. I'm new in programming. I'll create a new `View`. Now, my confusion is how will I pass the new `View` to the `setContentView()` method. I think I can call the `setContentView()` only once inside the `onCreate()`.

Comment: I understood now. I'll try to implement and check if it works. Thanks for your suggestion.